# solr php extension fails to run on newest Debian Wheezy

Tags: php5, solr, debian-wheezy

I'm trying to use the Solr PHP extension on the recently-upgraded Debian Wheezy. It installs both from PECL and from sources flawlessly but instead of giving me expected functionality it gives me this on every PHP run:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php5/20100525/solr.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/solr.so: 
undefined symbol: curl_easy_getinfo in Unknown on line 0
```

Also scripts which use the extension throws an error

```
PHP Error[2]: include(SolrClient.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in file <...path to my autoloader...>
```

My main point is that it was set up before and worked like a charm. In the upgrade among the relevant packages only the versions of PHP and libcurl was changed. Instance of Solr itself was left as is.

I have all possible `libcurl` libraries:

```
$ locate libcurl
...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.la
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.2.0
...
/usr/lib32/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib32/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib32/libcurl.so.4.2.0
...
```

I have instaled the `php5-curl` package version 5.4.4-2 with aptitude.

I installed the Sorl extensions both with

```
sudo pecl install solr
```

(with various combinations of `-f` and `-n` flags and tried `solr-beta` too) and with

```
wget ...
cd ...
phpize
./configure
make 
make install
```

I'm installing the 1.0.2 version of extension because it worked before the upgrade from Squeeze to Wheezy. As I said earlier, extension installs without any errors.

I have already added the `extension=solr.so` incantation to the `/etc/php5/mods-available/solr.ini`

What magic should I do to make solr extension work? Is this true that the only solution that I have is to downgrade the libcurl version as it was before the upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found the answer myself. Problem was in the errors in configuration. On newest Wheezy the config tree for PHP is as follows:

```
/etc/php5/mods-available/*.ini # here's the ini files containing `extension=modulename.so` lines and module-specific config.
         /conf.d/NN-*.ini      # here's the symlinks to real .ini files in mods-available
         /cli/conf.d           # symlink from local CLI conf.d to global conf.d 
         /apache/conf.d        # symlink from local apache conf.d to global conf.d
```

So I needed to do the following things:

- Add a file `/etc/php5/mods-available/solr.ini` with the line `"extension=solr.so"`
- Add a symlink `/etc/php5/conf.d/30-solr.ini` pointing to real solr.ini
- Do the same thing to `curl.so`
- Ensure that the `"extension=solr.so"` and `"extension=curl.so"` is not written *anywhere* else. That was the cause of this strange error message.

I think that the config become messy because of recent upgrade from Squeeze to Wheezy, because all of this configuration set-up should be really done by the package manager.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the same error.

FWIW - What worked for me was moving "extension=solr.so" from the top of my php.ini file to the bottom - obviously order is important and the curl extension need to be pulled in first.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Yeah, basically, all this work with separating of `extension=XXX.so` to several distinct files in `/etc/php5/conf.d/NN-XXX.ini` is about it: to ease the management of loading all this extensions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone under CentOS 6.4, this did it for me. Thanks to hijarian, this is an adaptation of his answer.

After installing everything and compiling the solr.so extension make a new `solr.ini` file under `/etc/php.d`

Using nano, for instance:
`nano /etc/php.d/solr.ini`

Add a line to that file containing `extension=solr.so`, save and exit.

Open `/usr/php.ini` file and add `extension=solr.so` to it also, save and exit.

Restart apache...

`/etc/init.d/httpd restart`

and you should be all done!

Answer (score 0):

curl module must be loaded BEFORE solr module.
So, make shure you have something like this in conf.d :
20-curl.ini
30-solr.ini (and not 10-solr.ini)

Or juste add "extension=solr.so" after your "extension=curl.so"